# Why are symfony flash messages not removed from session?

Tags: php, symfony, shopware6

I wrote a controller in Shopware 6 (symfony based) that adds a flash messages via `$this->addFlash(...)`.

As expected the message is shown in the storefront (product detail page).

In the function `\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Flash\FlashBag::all` the message is removed as expected (checked via xdebug).

But when I refresh, the flash message is shown again and is also contained in the session.

I also checked this directly in the PHP session:

`$_SESSION['_symfony_flashes']`

The message is correctly removed there, but reappears on the next page load.

The only idea I have is, that the session is not persisted after the flash message is removed from it. But I never faced such behavior in the Symfony sessions or PHP sessions.

What could be the reason for this?

Comment: Are you certain that you are not calling `addFlash()` again on each request?

Comment: @ArleighHix Yes I am certain. The flash message is created in a separate Controller that is only called when clicking a specific button. After that the customer is redirected back to the product detail page.

Answer (score 1):

My best guess is that the page is cached with the flash message intact. Afaik flash messages are primarily used on routes that are exempt from caching. The product detail page is not one of those by default. You might have to enrich the cache key for the page by a parameter denoting whether the flash message should be shown or not.

Comment: This cannot be the reason. The flash message is not only shown on this specific product detail page but on every page that is opened afterwards. I can e.g. click through 10 category pages afterwards and the message is shown again and again. Btw. the problem occurs on my local dev, where http cache is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to dneustadt's answer: As the product detail page is cached, also your flash message will *not* show if the detail page is generated and cached without the `addFlash()` and later your condition for the `addFlash()` becomes true: Then your controller will just not be hit and the cached page without the flash message will be shown.

Comment: Thanks. I am aware of this behavior and will modify the http cache key via EventSubscriber if needed.